# Learn python the hard way course Ex 25 NameError:

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

I get this error when I try and run this script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'print_first_word' is not defined
```

I'm not sure what it means as when I run `import E25; dir(E25)` it lists `print_first_word` in the `dir(E25)` result.

I'm running python 2.7.9 on Windows

```
def break_words(stuff):
     """ this function will break up words for us."""
     words = stuff.split('  ')
     return words

def sort_words(words):
     """ sorts the words."""
     return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
     """ prints the first words after popping it off."""
     word = words.pop(0)
     print word

def print_last_word(words):
     """ prints the last words after popping it off."""
     word = words.pop(-1)
     print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
     """ takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
     words = break_words(sentence)
     return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
     """prints the first and last words of  a sentence."""
     words = break_words(sentence)
     print_first_word(words)
     print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
     """sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
     words = sort_sentence(sentence)
     print_first_word(words)
     print_last_word(words)





     import E25
2 sentence = ”All good things come to those who wait.”
3 words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
4 words
5 sorted_words = ex25.sort_words(words)
6 sorted_words
7 ex25.print_first_word(words)
8 ex25.print_last_word(words)
9 words
10 ex25.print_first_word(sorted_words)
11 ex25.print_last_word(sorted_words)
12 sorted_words
13 sorted_words = ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
14 sorted_words
15 ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
16 ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

You imported `E25` but you are using `ex25.prin....` which is not the same as `E25.print...`.
According to your error though you are not using E25 or ex25 to call the function.

You might also want to change  `words = stuff.split("   ")` to   `words = stuff.split()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply  when im running the file im running all commands through E25 as that is my file i have saved

Comment: thanks for the reply when im running the file im running all commands through E25 as that is my file i have saved

Comment: @LibertySIlver, what is  `ex25` then? You could not be using `E25.print` as that would cause a different error unless you have called `print_first_word` in E25 somewhere before you defined it , the error says the very first line which also does not match your provided code

Comment: @LibertySIlver, where does ex25 come from, the code you posted could not possibly be correct as the traceback points to line 1 and a nameError not a module has no attribute error

Comment: i coppied and pasted the last part from the book thats why there all not changed to E25  the script itself is E25 .... it shouldnt give any errror its when i run in cmd under pythonor if i run it under shell  i get a error witch dose not make sense to me

Comment: Post the actual code you are using, using the actual name of your script

Comment: ignore the seccond part those are questions/ commands for powershell  the code your looking at is E25 line one ... is def break_words(stuff): not print_words_first

Comment: its posted what do u mean ,   everything till you get to the bottom is the code im currently using the rest are commands to ask the script ... if i run it   i get no errors when i open POWER shell import E25 and starting listing the commands i get a error on print_words_firstword(words) or w.e the code is there

Comment: I mean E25 is not ex25, nowhere in line 1 of either script has print_first_word which is where you error is coming from. Do you have any old .pyc files in the directory?

Comment: yeah nothing seems to be working other bits of the script works just couple parts giving me errors .....

Comment: You need to add the file contents, the exact name of the file you are importing from and the exact way you are calling the functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you might have two spaces between the single brackets; try to limit to one and try, I tried to remove space by just putting `''` instead of `' '`, and the code did not work.
2. Delete the pyc file from the folder and restart your powershell
3. Try to run the process again, but in case your folder is somewhere on your desktop like me instead of just from the C drive, try to go back to your location first by the set-location command; once you are in the folder, type "python" to go back to the >>> and start the practice.

I hope this helps

```
def break_words(stuff):
     """ this function will break up words for us."""
     words = stuff.split('^')
     return words
```